# Simulated world, when you go somewhere you normally do not go you see the simulation border

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is a movie I did not watch fully but it is still on my inner watch list. I hope I can provide enough details to identify it.

The world is somehow a simulation.  When you travel to a place where you normally do not go you can see the edge of simulation surfaces.  The reason is that these areas were not rendered for you.  I believe there are people who wish to escape simulation.

Comment: When did you watch this movie? Was it 3d or live play only?

Comment: It was live but with special effects. Interesting that the Twilight Zone had something similar - but not uncommon in the Sci-Fi world...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be ***[The Thirteenth Floor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139809/)*** (1999)...?

From IMDB:

> A computer scientist running a virtual reality simulation of 1937 becomes the primary suspect when his colleague and mentor is murdered.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thirteenth_Floor):

> McBain informs Hall that Jane does not exist, as Fuller never had a daughter. Hall tracks her down only to discover her double, Natasha Molinaro, working as a grocery store clerk, but Molinaro does not recognize Hall. **This leads Hall to perform an experiment outside the VR system, something that Fuller's letter instructed him to try: drive to a place where he never would have considered going otherwise. He does so, and discovers a point beyond which the world becomes a crude wireframe model. Hall grasps the revelation behind Fuller's message: 1999 Los Angeles is itself a simulation.**

[image]

Comment: Excellent and so fast! Many thanks, that's very likely it (need to watch it to know for sure)!

Comment: Thirteenth floor is a remake of World on a Wire (TV -Fassbinder, Germany 1973)